# How to handle 1:N Foreign Key for CRUD in Spring MVC / Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web

I am trying to create an 'update' form for a CRUD web application. The classes related to my question are related in a **1:N** manner within the MySQL database.

I am having trouble finding an elegant solution for casting the *department* parameter to the correct type. I could construct an ugly workaround with the form's jsp, but I would like to know what the *standard* SpringMVC / Hibernate solution is.

I have the following Hibernate entity classes, **Employee** and **Department**, implemented with the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DEPT", referencedColumnName = "ID_DEPT")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Department deptId;
 ...
}
```

The *update* is performed via a post request in a jsp file, as follows:

```
                    <form:hidden path="idEmployee" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deptid" class="col-md-3 control-label">Department</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form:input path="deptId" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>  
....
```

The post request will not provide the correct type for the **deptId**, throwing a type mismatch error.

Controller code for the saveEmployee action is:

```
@PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
public String saveDisciplina(@ModelAttribute("employee") Disciplina theDisciplina) {
    return "redirect:/employee/list";
}
```

Relevant code concerning EmployeeDAO is:

```
@Override
public void saveEmployee(Employee theEmployee) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theEmployee);
}
```

Where and how should I handle the post parameters correctly?

Comment: did you see what data it has posted to controller? i.e., What is value of deptId in your post controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be mistaking the understanding of the joined entity, because java stores the entity's reference. and you have to find it in hibernate with the reference when you update it.

Take a look at this example, and I hope it might help you :

https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

Answer (score 0):

What actually needs changing is just this line in the jsp update form:
`<form:input path="deptId" cssClass="form-control" />`

The proper path in this case would be `path=deptId.deptId`. This calls the appropriete constructor for the **Department** class which in turn instantiates a **Department** object to be saved as part of the **Employee** object which contains it.

Too bad such great functionality has such poor documentation. A Spring noob can easily feel overwhelmed. The only reason I'm including this paragraph is so that maybe someone will comment a link pointing to proper Spring documentation, as I was unable to find any to suit my needs.

Someone please correct my solution if it's wrong, but so far I've tried it with forms for create and update actions and it works fine.